# Почему вместо результата функции, в консоли, я получают ее текст, вместо значения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно вывести текущую длительность видео - 60 секунд. Но если это первые 60 секунд видео, то получится отрицательная длительность. По этому нужно приравнять отрицательные значения к 0.
Попробовал так, но не работает. Подскажите что я сделал не так? Можно ли решить задачу проще?

```
let momentTime = function() { 
    var videoTime = parseInt(document.querySelector('video').currentTime) - 60;
    if ( videoTime > 0) {
        videoTime
    } else {
        0
    }
};
console.log(momentTime);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция не возвращала результата. Надо добавить `return` перед тем значением, которое должно быть возвращено функцией.

```
let momentTime = function() { 
    var videoTime = parseInt(document.querySelector('video').currentTime) - 60;
    if ( videoTime > 0) {
        return videoTime
    } else {
        return 0
    }
};
console.log(momentTime());
```

Или это же можно сократить немного

```
let momentTime = function() { 
    var videoTime = parseInt(document.querySelector('video').currentTime) - 60;
    return videoTime > 0 ? videoTime : 0;
};
console.log(momentTime());
```

Comment: Спасибо. Есть нюанс, потом вывожу на экран ```let comment = `<span>` + momentTime + `</span>`;``` и получается вот такой текст на странице ```function() { var videoTime = parseInt(document.querySelector('video').currentTime) - 60; if ( videoTime > 0) { return videoTime } else { return 0 } }```

Comment: Вы наверное не обратили внимание... Вызов функции делается вот так `console.log(momentTime())` вместо `console.log(momentTime)`. Что бы вызвать функцию, указываем **()** после ее имени. `console.log(momentTime)` - это просто выведет текст функции в консоль

Comment: :)))) Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж @SwaD вам всё объяснил, то повторяться не буду, но приложу своё решение, где задача решена более простым путём.

```
let momentTime = function() { 
    var videoTime = parseInt(document.querySelector('video').currentTime) - 60;

    return Math.max(0, videoTime)
};
console.log(momentTime());
```

Функция теперь возвращает самое большое число, то есть, либо 0, либо *текущее_время_видео* - 60. Для примера: если *текущее_время_видео* - 60 = -1, то выберется 0, т.к. 0 > -1, а если *текущее_время_видео* - 60 = 2, то выберется 2, т.к. 2 > 0.

Comment: Интересное решение. Мне прям стало интересно, что выиграет по производительности, встроенная функция Math.max, if или тернарный оператор. Потестирую, сообщу результаты )

Comment: Лидирует тернарный, за ним math, последний if. Результаты [теста тут](https://codepen.io/SwaD1984/pen/yLqYeQQ) При больших количествах итераций, math и if выравниваются, но тернарный быстрее.

Comment: @SwaD попробовал у себя запустить два раза на Firefox 70+, Math работает быстрее во всех случаях, разница +- от 10 до пары тысяч, в пользу Math. Также попробовал на Firefox 108.0.1 (Последний на данный момент), везде тернарный побеждает, разница примера такая же как и в Math, но теперь в пользу тернарок. Интересно тенденция, с чего бы это?

Comment: Вот не знаю, сам удивлен результатом... Меня разочаровало, что IF проиграл ) Можно еще конечно в разных браузерах позапускать... Ну это уже так, когда совсем скучно. Может есть еще какие то механизмы кэширования данных в браузерах(типа мемоизации). Не знаю, но результат интересный

Comment: @SwaD А вы на каком браузере тестировали? Сам был удивлён поражению if'a :), позже попытаюсь на телефоне запустить в разных браузерах, для интереса... В принципе и сам процессор запоминает операции, это вроде тоже должно дать буст (для Intel'овских). Согласен, интересно получилось.

Comment: Я не в браузере пускал, а в node.js. Там же в кодепен по ссылке выше и результаты указал + скрипты(наверное не обратил внимания на это)

Comment: @SwaD попробовал на node.js, 50 на 50 получилось, иногда они были равны, иногда Math лучше, иногда тернарный оп. лучше, тоже как-то странно получилось. Но всё же тернарный оператор чаще был лидером.